# How to make a windows 7 loading bar on the taskbar

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a windows 7 loading bar on the taskbar. something like this:
[image: This is what I want]

I already have a jframe frame where a game loads in it.
I want to make the loadingbar show the progress of downloading the cache of the game. The jframe and the downloading are handled in two seperate classes.

When I looked on the web, I found 2 solutions.

1. SWT: where you can create the loadingbar, but I think you can't combine that with a jframe.
2. bridj: which is possible to add to jframe, but I don't have any idea how to do this with an existing jframe and the progress and the jframe handled in two different classes.

Comment: How is this different to the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482999/adding-a-taskbar-loadingbar-to-jframe)?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I had to re-ask because that question was unclear.

Comment: Hello again :-) - Have you tried extending the JFrame, as done in this example: https://github.com/nativelibs4java/BridJ/blob/master/src/main/demos/TaskbarListDemo.java

Comment: The [example code](https://github.com/nativelibs4java/BridJ/blob/master/src/main/demos/TaskbarListDemo.java) only uses a JFrame because that's easy for a demo. It's the instance of the `ITaskbarList3` object that does all the work and it's trivial to encapsulate that in any other class!

Comment: You can put a [`ProgressIcon`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3484251/230513) anywhere you can put an `Icon`.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a direct solution to what you ask since the progress task bar is OS unique, but *trashgod* actually got this answered at his post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483485/java-jprogressbar-or-equivalent-in-a-jtabbedpane-tab-title/3484251#3484251).
You could create an icon which is affected by your progress & update it, so the taskbar will show what you ask for.
I was inspired, so had to indicate it in case OP didn't catch this. Nice job!

```
private static class ProgressIcon implements Icon {

    private static final int H = 16;
    private static final int W = 3 * H;
    private Color color;
    private int w;

    public ProgressIcon(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void update(int i) {
        w = i % W;
    }

    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x, y, w, H);
    }

    public int getIconWidth() {
        return W;
    }

    public int getIconHeight() {
        return H;
    }
}
```