# GLFW loadding status on the taskbar

Tags: c++, glfw, taskbar

I need to make progres bar on taskbar using GLFW ( C++ ) , something like that:

[image: Image showing progres of windows copying files]

There is a simular question about java: [How to make a windows 7 loading bar on the taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526071/how-to-make-a-windows-7-loading-bar-on-the-taskbar), but I need it in C++

I was alredy looking for answer in GLFW's documentation, but I could not find any.

Is it possible using GLFW, and how can I do this? Let me know, if I can also make it work in linux or macOS.

If required, I might use native HWND window handler in Windows, but I was not able to find solution for native handler too.

Answer (score 2):

On windows you will need to use [`ITaskbarList3` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist3). `SetProgressState` and `SetProgressValue` method in particular.